# use routerLink with parameter that is coming from promise in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

i am working on an angular2 app.

i want to use  with a parameter that i get in a promise.

i keep getting this error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in http://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/app/components/some/some.component.html:0:7 caused by: c is null
>   normalizeCommands/_loop_1@http://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2384:15
>   normalizeCommands@http://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2427:11
>   createUrlTree@http://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2284:49
>   Routerhttp://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3486:18
>   RouterLinkWithHrefhttp://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4577:22
>   RouterLinkWithHrefhttp://localhost:5000/js/angular-client/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:4570:11
>   RouterLinkWithHref

this is my code:

some.component.ts:

```
someAnswer: SomeAnswer;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.getPromise(+params['id']);
    });
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
getPromise(id: number): Promise<SomeAnswer> {
    return this.http.get('/api/'+id+'')
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => this.someAnswer = response.json() as SomeAnswer)
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

some.component.html:

```
<h2><a [routerLink]="['/url', someAnswer?.id]">banana</a></h2>
```

so my question is - **how do i use [routerLink] with a parameter that i get from a promise?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found this blog post that answers my question:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

> The Safe Navigation Operator ensures that Angular won’t throw any errors when we’re trying to read from an object that is null or undefined
>   ... ... ...
>   adding Safe Navigation Operators everywhere can be quite tiring as well. In addition to that, some constructs **don’t support that operator**, like NgModel and **RouterLink** directives

so according to this post, routerLink does not support getting null parameters, and the parameter i'm passing (someAnswer?.id) is using the Safe Navigation Operators, and as it is received in a promise - when the page loads it is null.

there are 2 solutions to deal with that:

1. resolve the data before loading the component
2. instead of routerLink from the template - use `this.router.navigate()` from the component class

not being fond of forcing my async code to become sync, i decided to pass on the resolve option and chose the 2nd solution, this is how it looks:

some.component.ts:

```
goToPage(id:number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/url', id]);
}
```

some.component.html:

```
<a (click)="goToPage(someAnswer?.id)">banana</a>
```

hope this answer will help someone,

good luck

Comment: In order to use this.router.navigate, one first needs to import the router:

`import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

...and also to inject it into the constructor:

`constructor(private router: Router)`